# Issues Migrating Liferay 6.1 theme to 7

Tags: liferay, upgrade, liferay-6, liferay-7, liferay-theme

I've been following [these instructions](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/upgrading-your-theme-from-6-1-to-7-0), in an attempt to migrate a theme from our 6.1 portal to Liferay 7. The initial issue I seem to be having is getting the imported and upgraded theme to use `vm` as the template extension. I've added a `look-and-feel.xml` file containing the correct template-extension element to the 6.1 theme before importing/upgrading, but I am still receiving a "portal_normal.ftl not found" error after applying the theme.

Additionally, after importing and upgrading the theme into the Liferay 7 toolkit, the theme seems to only contain the child-specific theme files, and not the "compiled" set that would include the parent files (as it would had it been generated by the old sdk).

Any help resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The build process has been changed dramatically, don't expect the same mess of files to be copied into your current build environment. E.g. I wouldn't worry about the second half of your question, unless you can demonstrate that something is missing in the deployed theme or during build time. (I'll leave the first part for someone who already got their hands dirty with Liferay-7 themes)

Comment: also: Did you check what ends up contained in your theme's WAR file? is portal_normal.ftl in there?

Comment: It isn't, because we're trying to port 6.1 themes that use velocity.  The documentation states that this is possible and how to do it, but in practice Liferay doesn't want to recognize `vm` as a valid template file extension.

Comment: You could try manually converting the vm theme to ftl on 6.1 - AFAIK Freemarker is already supported for a long time. And it's preferable anyways, with a lot better error handling. Typically portal_normal is quite easy, not complex at all (though custom), so that a manual port might be easy. As you have the 6.1 environment, you can also easily test the ftl version in your existing environment before attempting the next upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay DXP/7 support freemarker. So your template files should be .ftl not .vm.You have to migrate template files into freemarker manually.

Regarding CSS: once you migrated theme, you will find a folder named 'src', you should make changes in files, placed here. Once you will find another folder over here named 'build'here you will find theme like we had in webapps in older versions.

Hope it will help